# Trying to add key:value pair to res.locals.object not working (Node / Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, object

I'm trying to build a `res.locals` object through multiple MongoDB operations, using `next()` middleware.

Once I've added an object to `res.locals`, for example: `res.locals.newObject`, next I want to add more `{key: values}` to the `newObject`.

Like this:

```
for(let i=0; i<res.locals.surveys.length; i++){
    await Answer.countDocuments({question_oid: {$in: res.locals.surveys[i].questions}).then((result) => {

        res.locals.surveys[i]["count_answers"] = result;
    })
}
```

I checked the object later, and it doesn't have the key or the value.

I also tried like this:

```
        res.locals.surveys[i].count_answers = result;
```

But that didn't work either. Is there a trick to res.locals objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use a for loop with an asynchronous call unless you are using async/await.  I advise you to learn a bit more about asynchronous code and what it means. There are numerous resources available online.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing

If you are using async await alter your code in the following way.

```
const result = await Answer.countDocuments({question_oid: {$in: res.locals.surveys[i].questions});
res.locals.surveys[i]["count_answers"] = result;
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. But that is fixing a different issue. The issue in this question is concerning adding the new `{count_answers: result}` to the `res.locals.surveys` object

Comment: You have to consider the order of events. First your loop executes and finishes and then the rest of your request handler probably finishes and the response is written. Then execution is handed over to waiting async tasks and the calls to count documents is executed. Only then will the callbacks come in and try to assign to a variable that is now out of its request handler scope.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question with `await`. However, it didn't fix my issue. As a test, I tried assigning `res.locals.count = 0` outside of the loop, and then reassigning the Mongo result inside the loop, and it works. However, when I tried to assign the Mongo result as an `res.locals.object.key` inside the loop, it didn't work... So I think this is something related to the `res.locals.object` not accepting the assignment.